# factories and unique numbers in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

d={'ID':["x1", "x2", "x1"],
'CUSIP':['a', 'b', "#NULL"],
'ISIN':["#NULL", "#NULL", 'I']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I am trying to replace all the '#NULL' with a unique number suffix. So, the output table will look something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

d={'ID':["x1", "x2", "x1"],
'CUSIP':['a', 'b', "#NULL_1"],
'ISIN':["#NULL_2", "#NULL_3", 'I']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Series` and add new values of filtered rows with `range`, last reshape back:

```
s = df.unstack()
m = s == '#NULL'
s.loc[m] = [f'#NULL_{x + 1}'  for x in range(m.sum())]

df = s.unstack().T
print (df)
   ID    CUSIP     ISIN
0  x1        a  #NULL_2
1  x2        b  #NULL_3
2  x1  #NULL_1        I
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to iterate through all values

```
count=1
for i in range(len(df)):
    for c in df.columns:
        if df.loc[i,c]=="#NULL":
            df.loc[i,c]="#NULL_"+str(count)
            count+=1
df

     CUSIP  ID     ISIN
0        a  x1  #NULL_1
1        b  x2  #NULL_2
2  #NULL_3  x1        I
```

To obtain the other order:

```
count=1
for c in df.columns:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i,c]=="#NULL":
            df.loc[i,c]="#NULL_"+str(count)
            count+=1
df

     CUSIP  ID     ISIN
0        a  x1  #NULL_2
1        b  x2  #NULL_3
2  #NULL_1  x1        I
```

Comment: ya, but but general rule in pandas is not loop, if exist some vecorized solution.

Comment: @jezrael But in comparison, this method is faster

Comment: In larger dataframe? 1000rows, 100 columns?